# ffmpeg upscaling and pixelating

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a rather small video I want to upscale while pixelating, though.

What I currently have is `ffmpeg -f gif -i test.gif -vf scale=w=-1:h=1080 test.mkv` however that tries intelligent upscaling and thus tries to smooth the borders, however I don't want that (due to various reasons...). However I couldn't find any information on how to do it, so, is that possible, and if so, how?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i test.gif -vf scale=-1:1080:flags=neighbor test.mkv`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a LOT! If you add itas an actual answer I can select it :)